# How to loop through a file and make each line a new regular expression into an awk statement?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, large-files

FileA.txt:

```
ATGCATGC 
GGGGGGTT
TTTTT
AAAA
```

FileB.txt:

```
asdfasdf
blah2
ATGCATGC
blah3
blah4 
delte-me-too
GGGGGGTT
blah5
blah5
....
```

I want to compare the each line from FileA.txt and check if it is in FileB.txt. If it is in FileB, I want to delete the following:

1. Matched Line
2. One line above
3. Two lines below

and output into a new file.

NOTE: There will be 500,000 lines in FileA. I would like to do this in a way which we do not hardcode the patterns.

I currently have something to delete the lines, but I'm getting tripped up about the looping through FileA to create a new pattern for this awk expression:

```
awk '/$VARIABLE_REGEX/{for(x=NR-2;x<=NR+2;x++)d[x];} {a[NR]=$0}
END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)
    if(!(i in d))
        print a[i]}' FileB.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: No error checking. Also, assumption is that the input in 2nd file follows the pattern mentioned exactly.

```
awk 'NR== FNR {a[$0] = $0 ; next } {if (!($0 in a)) {b[count++] = $0; } else {count--; if (count > 0) delete b[count];getline;getline; }} END {for (i=0; i<count; i++) print b[i] }' 1 2
```

inputs are in 1 and 2

1

```
ATGCATGC
GGGGGGTT
TTTTT
AAAA
```

2

```
asdfasdf
blah2
ATGCATGC
blah3
blah4 
delte-me-too
GGGGGGTT
blah5
blah5
foo
foo-delete
AAAA
bar-delete
bar-delete
bar-ok
```

Output

```
asdfasdf
foo
bar-ok
```

Comment: Thanks for the amazing response! The awk command works perfectly and the method is very clear. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Next code is not optimal (because it have to read *FileB.txt* twice) but hope it can be more quick then **awk**

```
comm --nocheck-order -23 FileB.txt <(grep -B1 -A2 -Ff FileA.txt FileB.txt)
```

With new **GNU sed** command `e` you can try (for memory saving) **sed** + **grep**:

```
sed 'N;h;s/.*\n//;s/.*/grep -xF "&" FileA.txt/e;/./{N;N;d};x;P;D' FileB.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with your sample

```
awk '
    NR==FNR {patt[$0]; next} 
    $0 in patt {getline; getline; getline; prev=$0; next} 
    {print prev; prev=$0} 
    END {print prev}
' fileA.txt fileB.txt
```

You have to keep all of fileA in memory, but you only need to remember one line at a time from fileB